# Google Chrome unresponsive on simple CSS page - how to fix?

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser

Google chrome (the tab) will become unresponsive when opening this page. Note that this seems to occur almost exclusively when you have just opened google chrome and navigated to the page (a fresh start, nothing in the history  yet).

http://users.telenet.be/prullen/grid.html

What can be seen when it is unresponsive is something like this:

[image]

Does anyone know what the cause of this is? I can't really do any debugging as the page is totally unresponsive and the developer tools cannot be loaded. Any pointers would be appreciated.

(Note: this is with chrome 15).

Edit:

This appears to be the code that makes it crash: But I really need this code. Any workaround?

```
 #container.grid .item {
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .15s linear;
-moz-transition: -moz-transform .15s linear;
-o-transition: -o-transform .15s linear;
-ms-transition: -o-transform .15s linear;
transition: transform .15s linear;
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-o-transform-style : preserve-3d;
-ms-transform-style : preserve-3d;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
}
#container.grid .item img {
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
}
```

Comment: I agree with Marc B. Have you tried on a different machine? Maybe it's the internet connection.

Comment: You could try to remove bits of your code until the browser doesn't hang - seeing as there is a quite limited amount of code here. Then post the code that is causing the problem, for people to look at.

Comment: No it's not the internet connection, I have been testing locally as well. And chrome shows the unresponsive dialog after a minute or so. Btw, why does google chrome tell me 15 is latest in the about dialog when 16 is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also tested in Chrome 16 - no console errors - watched for about two minutes, while continuously hovering in and out of thumbnails.  Monitored memory usage at the same time - no increase.  Sorry couldn't be of more help.

Comment: It seems to be fine in chrome 16. I was still on 15 and the about dialog did not report of a new version. (Claimed I was on the newest). Had to go and download on the official site. If people aren't being upgraded automatically, this is a problem that will still need to be fixed. Thanks though.